# Activation help

Tags: iphone, activation-lock

I used the Find My Phone app by mistake, and my iPhone is now requiring activation. It is asking me for my Apple ID and password... I have tried using it, but it won't activate. Please can someone help me to activate my phone.

Comment: Log in to the Apple Store with your Apple ID and password.

Comment: "I have used find my iPhone app by mistake" o.O' How can you do that ?

Comment: I don't know... It just happened, it was in my bag... And the next thing I know I can open it because it keeps asking me for the Apple ID and password

Answer (score 2):

In this case, your problem sounds simple (but as always, simple often doesn't mean easy). Your phone expects a particular Apple ID/password and you are not entering that combo. If one letter in either the email or password is off, it will reject it.

With that in mind, you have a few options. It is always possible that someone else has guessed your password, illicitly entered your account, and marked your phone as lost in addition to changing your Apple ID. This is worst case, and if such has happened, your only hope is to contact Apple. Otherwise, your phone is bricked.

A less pessimistic and probably more realistic outlook would be that you are just entering your credentials incorrectly and that your phone was marked as lost by chance (somehow that's hard to believe).

In this case refer to wherever you have your password saved on your computer and carefully copy that in. If you don't have it written down somewhere like [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword) (sorry for being blunt, but perish the thought of not having it recorded somewhere secure) then you will need to log on to [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com) and reset your password. Then, log in accordingly.

Unfortunately, computers almost never lie when they say that you entered your information incorrectly.